# htaccess with if HTTP_HOST does not work with Reqrite Rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` file on my Apache Server, which does not work

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.example.com'">
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.8\.8$
    RewriteRule .* - [F]

    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]

</If>
```

The code works fine without the if-Statement.
But with the if Statement

```
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

does not work. It throws a "404 Not Found error"

Comment: Are you sure you test for the right value here `www.somehost.com`? Did you try for example with another IP address than `192.168.8.8` to test for the 403 forbidden (assuring that the if condition is properly evaluated)?

Comment: Why the `if` command? Why don't you another rewrite condition for that? `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.example.com'">
>     RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.8\.8$
>     RewriteRule .* - [F]
>
>     RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
>
> </If>
> ```

The "problem" is because the mod_rewrite directives are embedded inside an `<If>` expression. `<If>` blocks are merged very late, after the request has been mapped back to the file system. In this context, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the absolute filesystem path, not a relative URL-path, so the second rule above will not match as expected.

So, the rule would need to be rewritten like this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/abs/file/path/to/docroot/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Or, more simply, remove the start-of-string anchor - although this does make the match somewhat ambiguous:

```
RewriteRule /([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Or, preferably, avoid the `<If>` construct altogether as you can get unexpected conflicts with other directives (outside of the `<If>` construct). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.8\.8$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

(The `NC` flag is not necessary in the 2nd rule, since you are already matching `A-Z` and `a-z` in the regex. ALso, use `^` instead of `.*` in the first rule, since you don't need to actually match anything here.)

If you have *many* such rules that apply to just this one host then you can reverse the logic and skip the *N* rules that follow when the requested host is *not* what is expected. For example:

```
# Skip the next 2 rules if the requested host is not "www.example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ - [S=2]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.8\.8$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I came myself to the following solutiuon. which i really like.

```
### Access control
###
###
# Set the environment variable if the HTTP_HOST matches 'www.somehost.com'.
SetEnvIf Host "www\.somehost\.com" IS_HOST=true

# Use the set environment variable in a conditional
RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HOST} true
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.8\.8$
RewriteRule .* - [F]



### Rewrite Urls
###
###
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```